# twisted python - sending message via GPIO that isn't received until the enter key is pressed

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, twisted, gpio

i have a occurrence with twisted python that i can't get resolved.

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(24, GPIO.RISING, callback=pDetected, bouncetime=1000)

def pDetected(channel):
    communicator.sendNotifications(factory)

class notification(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connection made but not added"

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        lineMessage = data.split('|')
        theCommand = lineMessage[0]
        theContent = lineMessage[1]

        if theCommand == "welcome":
            self.name = theContent
            self.factory.clients.append(self)
            print self.name + " has joined"

        elif theCommand == "msg":
            for c in self.factory.clients:
                c.message(msg)

        elif theCommand == "stopreactor":
            reactor.stop()

    def message(self, msgToSend):
        msgToSend += " \r\n"
        self.transport.write(msgToSend)

    def sendNotifications(self, theFactory):
        for c in theFactory.clients:
            c.message("notify " + c.name)

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = notification
factory.clients = []
communicator = notification()

reactor.listenTCP(myPort, factory)
reactor.run()
```

everything in the notification class works - clients can connect and messages can be sent/received without a problem using telnet.

When the event pDetected is fired, the callback to the pDetected works.  it sends the message (notify); however, the telnet session does not receive the message until i hit the enter key... every time.  none of the other clients see the message until the enter key is pressed.  i have run an analyzer on the port and the data isn't in the buffer.

can someone PLEASE identify what i am doing wrong?  i want the GPIO event to fire and to send a message to each client connected to the server.

any help is appreciated... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/), the callback that you are passing to `GPIO.add_event_detect` is a "threaded callback" - meaning, it runs on a new thread.

Calling a random Twisted API from a non-main thread is undefined - you will get random behavior.  What you've seen so far is needing to send it a new message to unstick the main loop, but other things can happen, including hangs and crashes.

The way you resolve this is with [`callFromThread`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.2/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorThreads.callFromThread.html), like so:

```
def pDetected(channel):
    reactor.callFromThread(communicator.sendNotifications, factory)

GPIO.add_event_detect(24, GPIO.RISING, callback=pDetected, bouncetime=1000)
```